# Converting a query to prepared statements - while loop a particular issue

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am just starting to learn php and have created a nice little page at

http://www.dowricks.com/index.php?route=information/yeast

I would now like to convert my queries to prepared statments  and have tried everything with no luck.

The section I would like to convert is as follows -

```
$q = 'SELECT yeast, rating, description, weblink
, image, sideimage 
FROM dowdb_yeast_selector 
WHERE fruit = "' . $_POST['fruit'] . '" 
ORDER BY rating DESC';  
            $r = @mysqli_query ($dbc, $q); // Run the query.

            // Present the results
            echo '<table width="100 px" cellspacing="15" cellpadding="15">';// Table header:
            echo '<tr bgcolor="green"><td colspan="5"><div class="yeast_heading" align="center"><em><b>The following yeasts are suitable for fermenting ' . $_POST['fruit'] . '</b></em></div></td></tr>';
            echo '<tr bgcolor="green"><td align="left">Yeast</td><td align="left">Rating</td><td align="left">Description</td> <td></td><td></td></tr>';
            // Fetch and print all the records....
            $bg = '#676767'; 
                    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) 
                    {
                        $sideimage = $row['sideimage'];
                        if ($row['rating'] == 3)
                        {$rating = "Best";}
                        if ($row['rating'] == 2)
                        {$rating = "Better";}
                        if ($row['rating'] == 1)
                        {$rating = "Good";}
                    $bg = ($bg=='#222222' ? '#676767' : '#222222');
                    echo '<tr bgcolor="' . $bg . '"><td align="left">' . $row['yeast'] . '</td><td><div align="center">' . $rating . '</div></td><td align="left">' . $row['description'] . '</td> <td><a href="' . $row['weblink'] . '" title="Go find">Buy</a></td><td><img src="' . $row['image'] . '" width="100" height="100" alt="Vintners Harvest Yeast" longdesc="' . $row['image'] . '" /></tr>';
```

If anyone could translate this for me I would be very grateful. 6 hours in and getting fed up.

Please let me know if you need any additional information.

Paul

Comment: You are not running any queries inside your while loop.  All you want to convert is $q and $r, unless I'm missing something.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=HOST;dbname=DATABASE', $user, $pass);

$stmt = $db->prepare('
    SELECT
        yeast,
        rating,
        description,
        weblink,
        image,
        sideimage 
    FROM dowdb_yeast_selector 
    WHERE
        fruit = :fruit
    ORDER BY
        rating DESC
');

$stmt->bindParam(':fruit',$_POST['fruit'],PDO::PARAM_STR,50);

$stmt->execute();

while ($row = $stmt->fetch())
    print_r($row);
```

I think you know how to manipulate `$row`

Comment: Worked perfectly.  Thank you.  All I need to do now is update my 2008 PHP MYSql manual and I will be able to work out what the hell is going on :-)

Comment: You have an updated manual here: [PHP PDO Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) ;)

Comment: I need more of a tutorial with loads of example I can follow and dissect.

Comment: @PaulDowrick I would suggest you to take my answer as correct. The PHP PDO manual has everything you need to know about prepared statements. What are you looking for: using a DBMS with PHP?

Comment: I think this manual will be very good when I get better, but for now I really need handholding and step by step walk throughs with explanations of why things are being done.  Hell, I am still not comfortable with MySQLi